# Flash drive OS experience

Tags: usb, flash

I was curious about installing an OS on a flash drive.  No I don't need to know the process which has been described elsewhere.  I wanted to know if there was any downside to installing on flash drive as opposed to other USB external drive.  Also, what has been your experience of it, issues that might arise, or benefits.

I am running a live Ubuntu from a Lexar flash drive right now on my work computer and it is surprisingly much faster than the work OS.  That really did surprise me.

Comment: Personally I've had no problems but I expect your question will be closed as "Primarily opinion based" You may wish to review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to know if there was any downside to installing on flash drive as opposed to other USB external drive. Also, what has been your experience of it, issues that might arise, or benefits.

To rephrase your question so as to be a little less opinion based:

> Is there any downside to installing on a flash drive as opposed to other USB external drives, also are there any issues that might arise, or benefits?

I have been using installed linux on usb drives for years. I have had/currently have multiple flash drives with multiple linux installs on the same drive. You can multiboot flash drives just like desktop/laptop hdds. The only downside i have ever run into was physical memory limitation. Booting the same drive on multiple computers sometimes you will run into a computer with less memory then the last one which may make your user experience different then the last computer you used it on. Becasue of this i always keep conky running with the physical ram listed.

I really only see benefits. You can take your computer with you (fits in your pocket). Also since your OS is running from a flash drive you will have almost SSD read/write speeds. Especially if you are using a USB 3.0 drive in a USB 3.0 port.

I guess if I had to say a downside is that you could lose your flash drive since it is small. Or accidentally run it through the wash.

Comment: This is a decent answer, so +1 but it is worth mentioning, a downside to using a USB install is speed. It just won't be as fast as running it from an HDD, this may bother some but it is not too bad if you need the portability.